# "Edit Active Target" xcode 4

Tags: ios4, xcode4

I am currently looking for the option "Edit Active Target" in xcode 4 which was previously at :

Project -> Edit Active Target from the menu.

I found someone telling to go to : View -> Navigators -> Project
but this does not give me active targets at all like in that picture : http://allseeing-i.com/i/add-linked-library.png

Does one of you know where to find that ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanting to add a linked library in Xcode 4, you click on the project at the top of the **Project navigator** (in the left hand pane).

Then click you're target under the **Targets section** in the pane that appears (where code usually is)

Then select the **Build Phases tab**, and expand the **Link Binary with Libraries section** to show the list of linked libraries and the buttons to add and remove.